# Unexpected EOF and Invalid Connection Beego ORM

Tags: mysql, go, beego

This happens when I already connected website and didn't do anything while and try to reconnect again I gets this error at first attempt.

> unexpected EOF, invalid connection

I found the error log:

```
[mysql] 2019/09/11 09:21:56 packets.go:36: unexpected EOF
[ORM]2019/09/11 09:21:56  -[Queries/default] - [FAIL /    db.Query /     0.0ms] - [SELECT T0.`i_d`, T0.`username`, T0.`password`, T0.`firstname`, T0.`lastname`, T0.`email`, T0.`stack_i_d`, T0.`stack_password`, T0.`default_tenant_i_d`, T0.`role`, T0.`created`, T0.`updated`, T0.`is_activated` FROM `user` T0 WHERE T0.`email` = ? ] - `EMAIL@YAHOO.COM` - invalid connection
```

And second try I successfully connect to website by login

```
[ORM]2019/09/11 09:23:46  -[Queries/default] - [  OK /    db.Query /     6.9ms] - [SELECT T0.`i_d`, T0.`username`, T0.`password`, T0.`firstname`, T0.`lastname`, T0.`email`, T0.`stack_i_d`, T0.`stack_password`, T0.`default_tenant_i_d`, T0.`role`, T0.`created`, T0.`updated`, T0.`is_activated` FROM `user` T0 WHERE T0.`email` = ? ] - `EMAIL@YAHOO.COM`
```